# Use sed to count periods, commas, and numbers?

Tags: bash, shell, sed, command-line, command

I have a file that looks like this:

```
19.217.179.33,175.176.12.8
253.149.205.57,174.210.221.195
222.118.178.218,255.99.100.202
241.55.199.243,167.98.204.104
38.224.198.117,21.11.184.68
```

Each line is 2 IP addresses, separated by a comma.  So, each line should meet these requirements:

- Has 1 comma.
- Has 6 periods.
- Has ONLY numbers, commas, and periods.

If a line is missing a period, has more/less than one commas, has a letter, is blank, or anything like that - it isn't correct.  Basically I just want to use `sed` or something similar to loop through each line in the file and make sure each of them meets the above requirements.

Is this something that can be done with `sed`?  I know you can use it to delete files that do/don't have matching strings, but I wasn't sure about counting specific characters or verifying that a line only has certain characters.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.  Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What I'd do is to think up a regular expression that fits the 'proper' lines, and omits them from printing. Like this:

```
sed -r '/^([0-9]{1,3}\.){3}[0-9]{1,3},([0-9]{1,3}\.){3}[0-9]{1,3}$/d' file
```

Everything that remains is a wrong line.

Here's the recipe in more detail:

- `[0-9]{1,3}` between one and three digits
- `\.` literal period (just the period is a wildcard and matches any character)
- `(...){3}` three repetitions of something, so together
- `([0-9]{1,3}\.){3}[0-9]{1,3}` makes up something that looks like an IP address. (Though note that it doesn't enforce the <256 rule, so `999.999.999.999` matches.)
- `/^ ... $/` the match needs to start at the beginning of the line and run until its end.
- `'/ ... /d'` print everything except lines that match what's inside the two slashes
- `-r` is needed to recognise the `{1,3}` syntax.

This will find and print the lines that are wrong. If you want to delete the wrong lines, you can easily invert this:

```
sed -i.bak -n -r '/^([0-9]{1,3}\.){3}[0-9]{1,3},([0-9]{1,3}\.){3}[0-9]{1,3}$/p' file
```

- `-i.bak` means keep a backup, but overwrite the input file
- `-n` means don't output anything unless expressly directed to output, and
- `/ ... /p` output all the lines that match this regex.

Answer (score 2):

I think `grep` is a better tool for this.  You just want to ensure that each line matches a particular regex, so invert the grep with `-v` and label the input invalid if any line gets output.  Something like:

```
grep -qvE '^([0-9]{1,3}\.){3}[0-9]{1,3},([0-9]{1,3}\.){3}[0-9]{1,3}$' input || echo input is valid
```

You can simplify that a bit:

```
IP='([0-9]{1,3}\.){3}[0-9]{1,3}'
grep -qvE "^$IP,$IP$" input || echo input is valid
```

Or if you are more interested in invalid data:

```
grep -qvE "^$IP,$IP$" input && echo input is invalid
```

Comment: That's also a nice solution.

Answer (score 0):

If you would like to display only information about file contents correctness , you can use this command:

```
sed -n -r '/^([0-9]{1,3}\.){3}[0-9]{1,3},([0-9]{1,3}\.){3}[0-9]{1,3}$/!{a \
FILE IS INCORRECT
;q;};$aFILE IS OK'
```

It's modified version of @chw21 answer, but displays only information text:

- FILE IS INCORRECT, or
- FILE IS OK.